# Can I take the battery out once film is in?

Tags: film, fujifilm, camera

If I take the battery out of my fujifilm instax mini 90 while film is inside will the film be wasted? Or can I take it out and still have my film inside once I place the battery back in

Answer (score 3):

Taking the battery out of the camera should not affect the film as long as you do not open the film compartment.

> **ONLY open the battery compartment door**.